# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-google-recaptcha' in '/tmp/build_67d6d8dd/src'

Tags: reactjs, npm, heroku, react-google-recaptcha

I tried to host my website with heroko and i got the following error:

*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-google-recaptcha' in '/tmp/build_67d6d8dd/src'*

I tried to implement react-google-recaptcha and is it working properly on localhost. I install the package with NPM.

Can you help me solving on this, please?

https://github.com/teocaragea/Porumbei-website

This is the repo that i used for building up my site.

Answer (score 2):

same issue here.. Just installed react-google-maps fresh first time by

```
npm i react-google-maps
```

Comment: i solved my problem by adding "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0" in package.json